# IEnumerable<T> Queue.Count is not returning an integer

Tags: c#

I am attempting to define a queue named movingAverages with a size of queue.Count - period.  I am getting an error "int IEnumerable.Count() ... - cannot be applied to method and int....

```
private static IEnumerable<DateClose> MovingAverage(
        IEnumerable<DateClose> queue, int period)
    {
        Queue<DateClose> movingAverages = new Queue<DateClose>(queue.Count + period);
        return movingAverages;

    }
```

Comment: Please edit your question to include the full source code and the full error message.

Comment: .Count() is a method, not a property. You need the parenthesis. Otherwise you're attempting to add the _method_ to an integer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well it's because `IEnumerable<T>.Count` is a method, so you are missing the parentheses at `queue.Count + period`, which should be `queue.Count() + period`.